# Websphere Plugin does not forward http custom error code 422 to the client,instead shows a 500 error message

Tags: websphere, ibmhttpserver

Websphere Plugin does not return the http custom error code 422 to the client,instead shows a 500 error message.
This is on WAS 8.5.5.9,IBM Http Server.

Comment: Works just fine here, what was the result in http_plugin.log? Can you enable TRACE in plugin-cfg.xml?

Comment: Yes,I've enabled trace.  This was the error in the plugin log.

Comment: [Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - DETAIL:    HTTP/1.1 422 
[Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - ERROR: lib_htresponse: htresponseRead: Response code 422 received. Error occured in reading response 2.
[Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - DEBUG: lib_htresponse: htresponseSetError: Setting the error to: |INVALID_FORMAT|(3, Line: 772)
[Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - ERROR: ws_common: websphereExecute: Failed to read from a new stream; App Server may have gone down during read

Comment: [Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - TRACE: ws_common: ServerActionfromReadRC: Request timed out.  Won't retry since PostBufferSize is 0.
[Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - STATS: ws_server: serverSetFailoverStatus: Server SI0VM1893Node02_VKS : pendingRequests 0 failedRequests 1 affinityRequests 0 totalRequests 0.
[Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - ERROR: ESI: getResponse: failed to get response: rc = 11
[Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - DEBUG: ESI: esiHandleRequest: failed to get response

Comment: [Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - DEBUG: ESI: esiRequestUrlStackDestroy
[Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - DEBUG: ESI: cacheURL: '/vks/rest/1/profile'
[Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - DETAIL: ESI: esiRequestPopUrl: '/vks/rest/1/profile'
[Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - DEBUG: ESI: esiUrlDestroy: '/vks/rest/1/profile'
[Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - ERROR: [10.4.103.136://vks/rest/1/profile] ws_common: websphereHandleRequest: Failed to handle request rc=11

Comment: [Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - DEBUG: ws_common: websphereCloseConnection
[Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - DEBUG: lib_stream: destroyStream: Destroying the stream
[Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - DEBUG: lib_rio: rclose: socket 4064 closed
[Tue May 03 07:41:10 2016] 00005838 00001efc - DETAIL: ws_common: websphereEndRequest: Ending the request

Answer (score 0):

However you are setting that 422 status, you need to make sure a word follows the status code. In my test, if you use HTTPServletResponse#setStatus and an unknown status code for example, WAS adds the word "Undefined" at least.

The safest way is to use HTTPServletResponse#sendError which requires a status code and a reason string.

Comment: Okay.
The actual error message from the browser/applcation is:
Error
-status:500
-error:undefined
-exception:undefined
-message:undefined

instead of the 422 response

Comment: That's not really pertinent.  Your log says the status line was " HTTP/1.1 422" which is invalid. There needs to be a reason-phrase after the status code.  sendError() requires you supply both.  How do you generate the 422 in your code?

Comment: Okay. I will have to check.
Thanks.

Comment: Also,it works fine when I access the application server directly.